# Many to Many Relationship: How to check a model's sub-model already contain other sub-model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a many to many relationship:

this following been created three model

1. Users
2. Meetings
3. Participants (join table)

Their relationship is simple:

1. One User have much Meetings
2. One Meeting have much Users

**So:**

> What's the best way to check **User.Meettings** contain Other specify **Meeting**

**I try to:**

> I try to use **include?** method, But rails give a **error**: **Column
>   in order clause is ambiguous**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `User` model

> has_many :participants
>
> has_many :meetings, :through => :participants

In your `Meeting` model

> has_many :participants
>
> has_many :users, :through => :participants

In your `Participant` model

> belongs_to :meeting
> belongs_to :user

Then, you can do something like

> User.first.meetings # returns first user meetings
>
> Meeting.first.users # returns first meeting users

I dono if this the best solution,

> Collect the ids or meeting_names using `collect` method and then use
> `include?` method on the array, which returns true of false

Comment: Thanks, And how can i know User contain a **specify meeting** ? I try to use **include?** method, But rails give a error **Column in order clause is ambiguous**